# Why don't we improve captcha?

Tags: bug

I just wrote a self-answered question on the main site. The answer is really long, and frankly speaking, it takes some time getting all the diagrams right, researching, making sure the explanations are lucid etc. So, I started yesterday evening (IST) and then I stopped for the night and continued today morning (IST)

This is what I was shown when I tried to publish it:

[image]

Now, I am fine with that, I understand: we don't need bots running the sites, we need humans with flesh and blood. But, when I went ahead to tick the box:

[image]
[image]

It comes right back to being unticked. Now, occasionally if this happens, I am fine with it, but this is happening the **third time** in a row!

Eventually, it allowed to continue after I tried it in a new window. I don't know the technical aspects of how captcha works, but why is this happening? Is it because of some server error, that this thing happens every time, or is there something else?

Also, the captcha looks pretty outdated. Again, I got no clue on how AI or scripts work, but it seems that a script can be well-equipped to tick a box. So, why don't we get something more advanced and efficient: like the ones where you have to select a letter or tick some images with certain objects in it? Why cant we improve captcha, both error free versions and more challenging ones?

Comment: Questions about things, like captcha, that affect all sites on the network are better suited to MSE, eg https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1343/334566

Comment: @PM 2Ring, I posted it there too. What now? Do I delete this, or let it be here?

Comment: You can delete this if you like, but it won't hurt to leave it here.

Comment: @PM 2Ring thanks, I think for now I will leave it here.